# A http request to google maps api direction with waypoints

Tags: java, android

How to fix this.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.3916642,78.4346606&destination=78.4382585808635,17.3813395082035&%20waypoints=optimize:true|17.3916642,78.4346606|17.3865225743848,78.4374928101897|17.3813395082035,78.4382585808635&sensor=false

This is the answer I get:

```
 {"geocoded_waypoints" : [ {}, {} ],
       "routes" : [],
       "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

Can one help me understand what is wrong? Does my request has an error, or I'm bypassing the limits of the direction google maps api?

Comment: hmmm, you seriously wana get to the Svalbard?

Answer (score 1):

Did you flip latitude and longitude on your destination?
With this link it works (I flipped them back): [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.3916642,78.4346606&destination=17.3813395082035,78.4382585808635&%20waypoints=optimize:true|17.3916642,78.4346606|17.3865225743848,78.4374928101897|17.3813395082035,78.4382585808635&sensor=false](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.3916642,78.4346606&destination=17.3813395082035,78.4382585808635&%20waypoints=optimize:true%7C17.3916642,78.4346606%7C17.3865225743848,78.4374928101897%7C17.3813395082035,78.4382585808635&sensor=false)

**edit**
There is a `%20` (urlencoded space) in front of waypoints, after removing you get:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.3916642,78.4346606&destination=17.3813395082035,78.4382585808635&waypoints=optimize:true%7C17.3916642,78.4346606%7C17.3865225743848,78.4374928101897%7C17.3813395082035,78.4382585808635&sensor=false